# Como conectar un input con el store

Tags: vuex

tengo un input en un componente el cual es responsable de enviar el query para que mi API ejecute la función para llamar a una API externa y traerme información. Esta función es despachada por un commit desde mi store.

Me imagino que con un $emit podría lograr conectar el input con el API pero no tengo idea de [image: como] hacerlo. o hacerlo directamente desde el componente al store.?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor añade texto en lugar de imágenes

Comment: Michael Linares Te refieres a modificar el valor de un state de vuex desde un input?

Comment: tengo que enlazar el input con el store para poder realizar la peticion o la otra opcion es enviarle el input al componente que realiza la peticion con un emit pero lo he intentado de mil formas y no he dado con la mejor opcion.